# How to change/remove Firefox Inspector Ctrl + Shift + C

Tags: firefox, browser, firebug, keyboard-shortcuts

Since `firefox v25` it has grabbed `Ctrl + Shift + C` for its own inspector and I now have to right click on elements and inspect to use firebug.

How can I change or remove this shortcut?

I have tired `about:config` and search in their but can only find firebugs shortcuts.

Answer (score 7):

You can turn off firefox inspector (here screen in Polish lang):

[image: how to turn off firefox inspector]

Then shortcut shouldn't work.

Comment: brilliant, I thought this would turn it off completely. [edit] Indeed, it does turn it off completely. Not ideal but ok.